# I was trying to run a java class file and a jni error occurred

Tags: java

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld ha
s been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up
to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I've been reinstalling both JRE and JDK for several times and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the JRE your using is older than the JDK used to compile your class. The key info here in the error message is:

> ... HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Based on the class file versions the JRE your using was probably released 5 years ago? You will either need to:

- Update the JRE to the latest version (better option)

OR

- Install a matching older JDK so you can compile classes compatible with your current JRE.

NOTE: If you have installed a more recent JRE version and you run `java -version` from a terminal does the version given match what you installed? If not, check your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables - they're probably pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: I have installed a version 8 JRE and it did show up in the terminal

Comment: That JRE is too old to run your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers - has a list of supported class versions.

Comment: So I guess I need to download a JRE of version 12? But perhaps I am just too stupid, I couldn't find a more updated version of JRE than the one I have

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you have done so far, and describe the system your working on, and how you installed JRE/JDK?